# cloud-init execution order doesn't respect /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg?

Tags: user-data, cloud-init

This is the content of `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` of Ubuntu cloud 16.04 image:

```
# The top level settings are used as module
# and system configuration.

# A set of users which may be applied and/or used by various modules
# when a 'default' entry is found it will reference the 'default_user'
# from the distro configuration specified below
users:
   - default

# If this is set, 'root' will not be able to ssh in and they
# will get a message to login instead as the above $user (ubuntu)
disable_root: true

# This will cause the set+update hostname module to not operate (if true)
preserve_hostname: false

# Example datasource config
# datasource:
#    Ec2:
#      metadata_urls: [ 'blah.com' ]
#      timeout: 5 # (defaults to 50 seconds)
#      max_wait: 10 # (defaults to 120 seconds)

# The modules that run in the 'init' stage
cloud_init_modules:
 - migrator
 - ubuntu-init-switch
 - seed_random
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - growpart
 - resizefs
 - disk_setup
 - mounts
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - update_etc_hosts
 - ca-certs
 - rsyslog
 - users-groups
 - ssh

# The modules that run in the 'config' stage
cloud_config_modules:
# Emit the cloud config ready event
# this can be used by upstart jobs for 'start on cloud-config'.
 - emit_upstart
 - snap_config
 - ssh-import-id
 - locale
 - set-passwords
 - grub-dpkg
 - apt-pipelining
 - apt-configure
 - ntp
 - timezone
 - disable-ec2-metadata
 - runcmd
 - byobu

# The modules that run in the 'final' stage
cloud_final_modules:
 - snappy
 - package-update-upgrade-install
 - fan
 - landscape
 - lxd
 - puppet
 - chef
 - salt-minion
 - mcollective
 - rightscale_userdata
 - scripts-vendor
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - scripts-user
 - ssh-authkey-fingerprints
 - keys-to-console
 - phone-home
 - final-message
 - power-state-change

# System and/or distro specific settings
# (not accessible to handlers/transforms)
system_info:
   # This will affect which distro class gets used
   distro: ubuntu
   # Default user name + that default users groups (if added/used)
   default_user:
     name: ubuntu
     lock_passwd: True
     gecos: Ubuntu
     groups: [adm, audio, cdrom, dialout, dip, floppy, lxd, netdev, plugdev, sudo, video]
     sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
     shell: /bin/bash
   # Other config here will be given to the distro class and/or path classes
   paths:
      cloud_dir: /var/lib/cloud/
      templates_dir: /etc/cloud/templates/
      upstart_dir: /etc/init/
   package_mirrors:
     - arches: [i386, amd64]
       failsafe:
         primary: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
         security: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
       search:
         primary:
           - http://%(ec2_region)s.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
           - http://%(availability_zone)s.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
           - http://%(region)s.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
         security: []
     - arches: [armhf, armel, default]
       failsafe:
         primary: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
         security: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
   ssh_svcname: ssh
```

As you can see, `package-update-upgrade-install` is put in `final` stage, where `runcmd` is put in `config` stage. According to [cloud-init document](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html), modules in `config` stage are executed before `final` stage. As I understand, `runcmd` will be executed before `package install`.

However, the following code runs without any error:

```
packages:
        - shorewall

runcmd:
        - echo "printing shorewall version"
        - shorewall version
```

That means `runcmd` can be executed after `package install`.

Is there any reason that make `cloud-init` disrespect the execution order defined in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`?

Answer (score 6):

While investigating how to get cloud-init to run things earlier in the boot process, I saw this too.  In my testing, it appeared to me that runcmd was running in the config stage as you would expect, but all it was doing was creating a shell script from the runcmd data, which it put in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd.  Cloud-init then ran the shell script during the scripts-user module in the final stage.  Below are bits from the /var/log/cloud-init.log log showing this:

```
        "Mar 15 17:12:24 cloud-init[2796]: stages.py[DEBUG]: Running module runcmd (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_runcmd' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_runcmd.pyc'>) with frequency once-per-instance",
        "Mar 15 17:12:24 cloud-init[2796]: util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-xxx/sem/config_runcmd - wb: [644] 20 bytes",
        "Mar 15 17:12:24 cloud-init[2796]: helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-runcmd using lock (<FileLock using file '/var/lib/cloud/instances/i-xxx/sem/config_runcmd'>)",
        "Mar 15 17:12:24 cloud-init[2796]: util.py[DEBUG]: Shellified 1 commands.",
        "Mar 15 17:12:24 cloud-init[2796]: util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-xxx/scripts/runcmd - wb: [700] 50 bytes",
       ...
       "Mar 15 17:12:40 cloud-init[2945]: stages.py[DEBUG]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) with frequency once-per-instance",
        "Mar 15 17:12:40 cloud-init[2945]: util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-xxx/sem/config_scripts_user - wb: [644] 20 bytes",
        "Mar 15 17:12:40 cloud-init[2945]: helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-scripts-user using lock (<FileLock using file '/var/lib/cloud/instances/i-xxx/sem/config_scripts_user'>)",
        "Mar 15 17:12:40 cloud-init[2945]: util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=True, capture=False)",
```

Hope this helps...