# Where is CloudFormation template located on the instance, which is called by cloud-init?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I understand the [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) block of the template is executed by [cfn-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) script.

Here is the syntax I use to do so:

```
/usr/local/bin/cfn-init -v --stack  WebS<erver1 --resource WebServerInstance --region eu-central-1 --configset InstallAndRun && cat /var/log/cfn-init.log
```

I can do the call via UserData or via SSH.

Now I would like to have the possibility to modify the [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) part of the template and repeat the cnf-init call via ssh.

**Question:**
Where is the file with the cloud formation code located on my instance, which is executed by cfn-init?

Comment: Have you been able to find the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cfn-init` command uses a configuration file located at `/var/lib/cfn-init/data/metadata.json`. The JSON file contains the config sets defined in the AWS::CloudFormation::Init block of a Cloud Formation template.

I've confirmed the path above on Amazon Linux 2. The location on other operating systems may be different.

Answer (score 0):

All of the cloud init files are in /var/lib/cloud (on Centos 7) and the userdata script is in /var/lib/cloud/instance

See my other answer 
[cloud-init: What is the execution order of cloud-config directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095839/cloud-init-what-is-the-execution-order-of-cloud-config-directives/37190866#37190866)
for general hints on where the source to cloud-init is, execution ordering

Comment: Hi! Thnx for the response. Thats true, userdata is in /var/lib/cloud, but not the declarative AWS::CloudFormation::Init part. Where do I find this one, do you know?

Comment: The declarative part will be in the cloud  formation  template that you used to create the stack.  Identify the stack that you used and then modify the template

Comment: A downvote here is a bit harsh (fixed, haha). The answer itself points to a good resource that should answer the question without creating duplicate content on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Miles The answer described where to find the userData scripts. Indeed the question was: where to find the declarative part, described in the AWS::CloudFormation::Init part of the template. The usecase mentioned was: modification of the template locally and retriggering of the cfn-init with a modified template, to shorten the development cycle. So the answer missed the point IMHO

Comment: @sudheerchamarthi by "modify the template" you probably mean updating the stack with a new template?  Exactly this I would like to avoid in order, if I need to do a minor change and retrigger the provisioning - I would like to modify the declarative template ON THE INSTANCE and directly retrigger the cfn-init.