# How to import existing EC2 with EBS block device?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ebs

I want to use Terraform for my existing AWS infrastructure. Therefore, I imported an existing EC2 instance with EBS block devices. Then I wrote the Terraform code. But Terraform wants to replace all EBS block devices. Is there any way to not replace the EBS block devices?

**Import**

I imported my AWS EC2 instance as described in [Import](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#import):

> **Import**
>
> Instances can be imported using the id, e.g.,
>
> ```
> $ terraform import aws_instance.web i-12345678
> ```

**Code**

After I imported the state file, I wrote my Terraform code.

This is the part for the EBS block device:

```json
ebs_block_device {
  device_name = "/dev/sdf"
  volume_type = "gp2"
  volume_size = 20

  tags = {
    Name = "my-test-docker"
  }
}
```

**Plan**

After I wrote the code, I run the plan command, see [Command: plan](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/plan).

This is the part for the EBS block device:

```
- ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
      - delete_on_termination = false -> null
      - device_name           = "/dev/sdf" -> null
      - encrypted             = false -> null
      - iops                  = 100 -> null
      - snapshot_id           = "snap-0e22b434e3106fd51" -> null
      - tags                  = {
          - "Name"            = "my-test-docker"
        } -> null
      - throughput            = 0 -> null
      - volume_id             = "vol-065138961fea23bf4" -> null
      - volume_size           = 20 -> null
      - volume_type           = "gp2" -> null
    }

 + ebs_block_device { # forces replacement
      + delete_on_termination = true
      + device_name           = "/dev/sdf"
      + encrypted             = (known after apply)
      + iops                  = (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
      + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
      + tags                  = {
          + "Name"            = "my-test-docker"
        }
      + throughput            = (known after apply)
      + volume_id             = (known after apply)
      + volume_size           = 20
      + volume_type           = "gp2"
    }
```

**Research**

I tried to set the `volume_id` in my code, but Terraform didn't allow to set this property.

Actually, the EBS block device shouldn't be replaced after creation, see [ebs_block_device](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#ebs_block_device):

> - ebs_block_device - (Optional) One or more configuration blocks with additional EBS block devices to attach to the instance. Block device configurations only apply on resource creation. See Block Devices below for details on attributes and drift detection. When accessing this as an attribute reference, it is a set of objects.

**Background**

One of the reasons for using `ebs_block_device` instead of `aws_ebs_volume` with `aws_volume_attachment` was [aws_volume_attachment Error waiting for Volume](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4770) .

Another reason was

- [Ebs volumes are not attached and available at boot time for userdata script to mount them.](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6349)
- [AWS Attach/Format device with CLOUDINIT](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/aws-attach-format-device-with-cloudinit/2515)
- [fs_setup/disk_setup: option to wait for the device to exist before continuing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1832645)

`ebs_block_device` is still working fine for new (not imported) resources.

The formating and mounting part of my cloud-init user data script:

```
fs_setup:
  - label: docker
    filesystem: ext4
    device: /dev/xvdf
    overwrite: false

mounts:
  - [ "/dev/xvdf", "/mnt/docker-data", "auto", "defaults,nofail", "0", "2" ]
```

**Question**

Is there any way to give Terraform a hint to match EBS block device in code with EBS block devices in the state file?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `ebs_block_device`, you should be using `aws_ebs_volume` and  `aws_volume_attachment` resources to import non-root EBS blocks, according to Terraform docs:

> Currently, changes to the ebs_block_device configuration of existing resources cannot be automatically detected by Terraform. To manage changes and attachments of an EBS block to an instance, use the aws_ebs_volume and aws_volume_attachment resources instead. If you use ebs_block_device on an aws_instance, Terraform will assume management over the full set of non-root EBS block devices for the instance, treating additional block devices as drift.

Comment: The first issue about the error waiting for volume, was already fixed in AWS provider version v3.62.0, and the second error about timing issues with cloud-init can be resolved by adding a delay/retry job where you make an API call to the metadata server to retrieve EBS devices associated https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-categories.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. The first fix (terminate) didn't work for me, but maybe I did something wrong. I can't remember. For the second fix (delay): is there a cloud-init solution? That's the way I create my mounts and users.

Comment: No, there isn't a cloud-init native solution, but what I was suggesting is that before proceeding to mount the disk(s), you could add a shell script that verifies that the EBS devices are available(by using the metadata server) and then proceed with the next steps of creating and mounting the devices.

Comment: Do you mean in the `rundcmd` section of cloud-init?  I read that this section is not executed at the right time (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095839/cloud-init-what-is-the-execution-order-of-cloud-config-directives). Could you provide any link to an example?

Comment: Not with `runcmd` as that will run after `users` and `mounts` modules but with `bootcmd`